# DJANGO simplejson

Tags: django-views

Sorry i'm a beginner in django and python..i create a project and i've a models.py like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Shoes(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField() 
    number = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Shoes"

class Bottom(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    finish = models.BooleanField()
    size = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bottoms"

class Relation(models.Model):
    shoes = models.OneToOneField(Shoes)
    bottom = models.ForeignKey(Bottom)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Relations"
```

I want to serialize theese classes in json..sorry i need to understand where and how write the specific code to do it..
I wrote already a file views.py and a file.html to view a web page with table of theese objects, but now because i need to write a jquery function that allow to update the web page automatically when i add a new object, I think that we need to serialize the data in json before doing so.
Thanks and bear with me if I said something idiotic because i'm a really beginner in this field..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to serialize *classes*? You want to serialize objects! :) In order to serialize Django objects you can use built-in mechanisms. Read this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

For example you can do this like this:

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def someView(request):
    shoes_from_db = Shoes.objects.all()
    json = serializers.serialize(
             'json', shoes_from_db, fields=('type','start_date', 'number')
           )
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: and by utils with dumps to serialize and loads to deserialize is not better?? and so about urls.py what i can write to view json??

Comment: Django internally generates many fields which would be difficult to serialize using `simplejson`. Moreover Django `serializers` allow to serialize only those fields you want. It is a great simplification. As for the other question: I don't understand. You write urlpattern like any other pattern.